# Il significato del termine tiritomba

Tags: regional, synonym

Il significato del termine `tiritomba` è ancora sconosciuto?

Tiritomba   Canta: Roberto Murolo

```
Sera jette, sera jette a la marina
Pe' trovà 'na 'nnamurata,
Janca e rossa, janca e rossa, aggraziata,
Fatta proprio pe' scialà.
Tiritomba, tiritomba,
Tiritomba, tiritomba a ll'aria va
Tiritomba, tiritomba,
Tiritomba a ll'aria va.
```

Comment: Mi ha fatto venire in mente ["sarandonga"](https://m.letras.com/lola-flores/867154/), che non significa nulla (perlomeno che io sappia), è soltanto una parola inventata per fare una canzone.

Comment: Non potrebbe essere una voce onomatopeica costruita sul modello di "rataplan"?

Comment: “Ancora” rispetto a che cosa?

Comment: Ah, sì, @ZabZonk: esiste anche ["tirititrán"](http://www.flamenlove.com/2017/09/tirititran-tran-tran.html?m=1) che ancora si assomiglia di più.

Comment: @ZabZonk:    E poi c'è una [canzone popolare catalana](https://ca.m.wikisource.org/wiki/40_can%C3%A7ons_populars_catalanes/Els_tres_Tambors) in cui "rataplam" è, effettivamente, un'onomatopea per il suono di un tamburo.

Comment: Creerò un dizionario: Tiritomba = Prisencolinensinainciusol (Adriano Celentano) --- Sarandonga=Tirititran

Answer (score 1):

Credo sia una parola inventata, come spesso accade nelle canzoni. Usata solo per il suo suono.
Sono napoletano, e non ho mai sentito questo termine.

Answer (score 0):

Azzardo che potrebbe forse riferirsi al "Tiritomba Narcissus" ?

Forse un riferimento floreale ?  ("Tiritomba, tiritomba a ll'aria va")
e per estensione a persona vanitosa

https://www.backyardgardener.com/plantname/narcissus-tiritomba-narcissus/

Comment: Per quanto concerne ""sarandonga" citata da @Charo, ho letto sul web che si tratterebbe di parola cubana riferita ad un piatto tradizionale, anche ripresa in titoli di canzoni anni '50. Ma riferisco e basta... :-)

Comment: Ecco un altro che sostiene la tesi: https://lyricstranslate.com/tr/translator/berny-devlin?page=2&t=comments